# Supoose $A$ is semisimple, $f_A:\;X\to XA-AX,\;\forall X\in GL_n(\mathbb{F})$, $f_A$ is semisimple too.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

> $GL_n(\mathbb{F})$ is a linear space consists all $n\times n$ matrices over filed $\mathbb{F}$. Suppose $A$ is semisimple, prove that the linear transform 
>   $$
> f_A:\;X\to XA-AX,\;\forall X\in GL_n(\mathbb F)
> $$
>   is also semisimple.

$A$ is semisimple, so there exists an invertible matrix $P$, $\Lambda=PAP^{-1}$ is a diagonal matrix. So $f_{PAP^{-1}}=X\Lambda-\Lambda X$. What is the relation between $f_A$ and $f_\Lambda$, and how to find a base that the matrix representation of $f_A$ is diagonal.

Comment: How about considering eigenvectors of $f_A$?

Comment: If $A$ is semisimple you can just as well assume that it is diagonal. Can you prove that in the diagonal case the natural basis matrices $e_{ij}$ are all eigenvectors of $f_A$? See, for example, [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2585175/11619).