# Cartan-Weyl basis in terms of simple roots

Tags: lie-algebras, semisimple-lie-algebras

Let $\mathfrak{g}=\mathfrak{h} \oplus \bigoplus_{\alpha \in \Phi}\, \mathfrak{g}_\alpha$ be a complex semisimple Lie algebra, where $\mathfrak{g}_{\alpha}=\mathbb{C} \cdot e_\alpha$ is 1-dimensional. Moreover, let $\Delta \subseteq \Phi^+$ be a set of simple roots. It is known, that $\mathfrak{g}=\langle \, h_i,e_i,f_i \,| \, \alpha_i \in \Delta \, \rangle$, where $e_i=e_{\alpha_i}$, $f_i=e_{-\alpha_i}$ and $h_i=[e_i,f_i]$.

Let $\alpha = \sum_{\alpha_i \in \Delta} \,n_i \alpha_i \in \Phi^+$. How can we express $e_\alpha$ in terms of $e_i$'s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One has $\mathfrak g _{\alpha+\beta} = [\mathfrak g_\alpha , \mathfrak g_\beta]$, hence the root spaces $\mathfrak g_\alpha$ for $\alpha =\sum n_i \alpha_i$ can easily be expressed in terms of nested commutators of the root spaces $\mathfrak g_{\alpha_i}$. Cf. [What is the basis of the root space $\mathfrak g_\theta$, where $\theta = \alpha_1+\cdots+\alpha_n$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3472456/96384)

Then if for $\alpha \notin \Delta$ there is no restriction on $e_\alpha$ except that it is a vector space basis (i.e. non-zero element) of the (one-dimensional) space $\mathfrak g_\alpha$, obviously you can choose any in there. Be careful though that according to a specific definition of a Cartan-Weyl or Chevalley basis, there *are* further restrictions / relations, which might force you to carefully choose a correct scaling for each $e_\alpha$.

Note: One should be careful though to order the nested commutators in the right way. Compare [ladder operators of simple Lie algebra and simple roots](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4683781/96384).

Comment: Thx! I think then my question is rather if there is a way to determine the correct scaling for a given nested commutator

Comment: For example, what would be the scaling factor for $\alpha=s_i(\alpha_j)=\alpha_j-c_{ij}\alpha_i$ wrt the commutator $ad(e_i)^{c_{ij}}(e_j)=[e_i,[e_i,[\dots, [e_i,e_j] \dots]]] $?

Comment: Well that depends on what extra relation(s) you want. You have not written down any, and different sources use different normalisations.

Comment: Oh sorry, I think I missunderstood what you first said :) Thx!